# Does any Christian denomination use enough wine in the Eucharist that it could show on a breathalyzer test?

Tags: communion

Is there any Christian denomination in which members of the congregation are given enough wine in the Eucharist/Communion that their blood alcohol concentration as measured by a breathalyzer would likely be nonzero? (I'm not counting the minister, so if a priest has to consume excess consecrated wine as I believe is required in Catholicism, that doesn't count for the purposes of this question.)

Comment: Some churches use **port** wines. Some pastors get one of the faithful to consume the Wine that is not consumed at mass. This happens with me on some occasions. And yes I do not drive because I have felt a little uneasy about it.

Comment: This question is not about Christianity it’s more if a science/medical q

Comment: @User 14  This is most certainly about Christianity as it involves knowing how much wine is used in different Christian denominations. It also requires knowing which ones use alcohol, and which do not.  Only then can a quantity be established, a prerequisite for working out how much alcohol might be in an individual celebrant's blood system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personal communion cups are typically about 10mL, and many churches use port, which has an ABV of up to 20%.

Using [this calculator](https://www.drinkfox.com/tools/bac-calculator/aus), for a 50kg woman, they'd have an immediate BAC of 0.0043%. This takes 18 minutes for the body to fully process. If communion was given at the end of the service, and they were immediately breathalysed, then depending on the sensitivity of the device it might be able to detect something. But practically, it's unlikely to be an issue. However if someone's license required an absolute 0 BAC, then they might decide to wait that 18 minutes.

Comment: Wish the church I attended used port - we have a non-alcoholic fruit-based drink.

Comment: "absolute 0 BAC" is effectively impossible. Most fruits and juices naturally contain alcohol. Fresh bread is 2% alcohol. Sugars can ferment in one's own gut.

Comment: Note that not all churches use personal cups; a few pass around a shared goblet, so the amount consumed will depend on how much you sip.

Comment: @gidds.  That had always grossed me out.   But as long as you wear a dust mask before and after the gulp….

Comment: @RayButterworth Because I'm under 21 years old, under Oregon law, I would get a DUI if I were tested and the result was anything but zero. My BAC is likely nonzero due to sources other than alcoholic beverages, but if it were high enough to show at all on a breathalyzer, I would get a ticket.

Comment: @Someone, given that there exist religious exemptions for drinking age, I would be very surprised if you couldn't get such a ticket tossed by a judge, as long as you aren't actually over the legal limit (in which case your age wouldn't matter). Also, if the law actually allows a ticket in such circumstances, it probably violates the First Amendment.

Comment: @Matthew the limit for my age is zero. Any detectable alcohol in the bloodstream is considered being under the influence for minors.

Comment: @Someone, IANAL, but that still sounds like a First Amendment violation to me. It might be interesting to ask over on Law.SE, and I would expect that to get challenged in court if it hasn't been already. FWIW, I'm pretty sure I would have been in the position of driving home from church at *some* point before I turned 21, and I never gave it a second thought, but I didn't live in Oregon at the time. If you're really that worried, some churches offer non-alcoholic wine for those that need it.